# Windows Phone 8 Change Accent and Theme Colour

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating an Application for Windows Phone 8, and I would like to change the theme colour irrespective of the theme set by the user in the phone OS, in the same way that other applications do this (for example Skype).

So far I have only managed to change the background colour, by accessing the LayoutRoot element in XAML:

```
this.LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

And the Foreground Colour:

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Green;
```

However the following does not work on Windows Phone 8:

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Yellow;
```

I do not know why I cannot change the `PhoneBackgroundBrush` or the `PhoneAccentBrush` and I have tried googling solutions however they only work with the windows phone 7 SDK.The Tutorial [here](http://www.identitymine.com/forward/2010/11/theming-tips-for-windows-phone-7-wp7/) works on WP 7 but not WP 8.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Fabrice is definitely on the right track. Getting the default PhoneAccentBrush and changing it's color is the way to go.

Add this code to the end of your App's constructor and it would override WP8's Accent colour for your app:

```
    Resources.Remove("PhoneAccentColor");
    Resources.Add("PhoneAccentColor", Colors.Magenta);
    ((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = Colors.Magenta;
```

When we run this code and click a `<Button />` you can see the new Accent colour:

[image: Clicked button with Magenta background]

Comment: I tried this, by adding `using System.Windows.Media;` at the top of the `App.xaml.cs` file, and adding your code to the `App()` after `InitializeLanguage();`, however to no effect. I also put it at the start of the constructor but no difference.

Comment: This seems to work for some elements (such as Buttons and text styles) but not others. ApplicationBar, MessageBox and CheckBox don't pick up this color change. Maybe there's another style that needs overwritting, or some of these items might not be stylable in the same way.

Comment: ApplicationBar, SystemTray, MessageBox and a few others are shell UI which has nothing to do with XAML styles. So they won't be affected by this change. Some of these expose specific APIs to configure their UI while other don't.

Answer (score 8):

If you want different brushes, then create new brushes. No need to go through the trouble to replace existing ones. One day you may want to use those built in brushes.

I would suggest just adding new resources to your app and reference those.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppAccentBrush" Color="#012345"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In your pages, reference it like such

```
<TextBlock Text="Custom Accent" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
           Foreground="{StaticResource AppAccentBrush}"/>
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to the Windows Phone environment so forgive me, but where in the XAML file should your first code snippet be placed? I get the error `The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Application'`

Answer (score 3):

I saw a blog post a few days ago:

http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2013/01/18/forcer-un-theme-sous-windows-phone-8/

It's in french but don't be afraid.

There is a sample to change the color in Windows Phone 8 (check the method DarkTheme())

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I tried to use the DarkTheme Method, however nothing happens. I'm calling `DarkTheme();` after `InitializePhoneApplication();` in `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: Tried both method? The second one is called DarkTheme but it's not the same colors.

Comment: I had the Huyn method not change the background, but including the single file from [ThemeManager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager/blob/master/src/JeffWilcox.PhoneThemeManager/ThemeManager.cs) worked perfectly.