# windows phone 8 xaml set the color of a button on click

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on win8 phone project
whenever I click a button the buttons background changes to phones accent color or on a textBox the border color changes to phones accent color or the color of the keyboard buttons
changes to phones accent color ...
I tried to overwrite the PhoneAccentBrush in application.resources `< solidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneAccentBrush" color="white" />` but it didnt work
is there any way to change Phone Accent Color for all elements in my app ??

Answer (score 5):

You can change the default style of all Button controls in your app such that it doesn't use `{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}` in the `Pressed` state.

Open Blend and create a simple WP8 project, put a `Button` in it and then grab a copy of the template (right click on the button and Edit a copy). See [Jeff Wilcox's blog for a step-by-step description of the process](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/).

Then you can paste the template into your `App.xaml`. If you remove the `x:Key`it becomes the default style for that control.

Alternately you could check [this StackOverflow question about overriding the theme everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537071/windows-phone-8-change-accent-and-theme-colour).

Answer (score 3):

Without copying whole style with blend you can simply override default theme:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <!-- Button pressed color -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="OrangeRed"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

tested with wp8.1 at least, anyway I found out `ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush` with blend ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnSignIn.Background = GetColorFromHexa("#59BD56");
    }
    public SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
    {
        byte R = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16);
        byte G = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16);
        byte B = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16);
        SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, R, G, B));
        return scb;
    }
```