# Error when trying to set Grid.Background to accent colour

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, colors, grid

In my application the user can choose what colour they would like a particular feature of the app to be.

They can choose from a variety of colours which works fine, however when trying to set the Grid's background to the accent colours; when chosen, a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` error appears.

The code I am using is:

```
Color accentColour = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
gridColour.Background = new SolidColorBrush(accentColour);
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? (I've also tried using a Rectangle and it's `.Fill` property).

Thanks.

[SOLVED: Post solved in comments.]

Comment: Are you running this code at startup?  The only thing I can think of is that the app resources haven't loaded yet ...

Comment: That might be why, I can give it a try!

Comment: That was why, there was a check box where the user could choose a colour for an in-app feature. The grid is just a graphical display to show the user the selected colour. However by default the checkbox was already checked so the Checked event was triggered too early on in the process; before the recources had loaded! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that code in `OnNavigatedTo` Event. Its Working.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    Color accentColour = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
    ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(accentColour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can easily do this by binding the `PhoneAccent` color within your `XAML` for your Grid.

These threads would be helpful:

[Windows Phone 8 Change Accent and Theme Colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537071/)

[windows phone 8 xaml set the color of a button on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405554/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it via XAML however in this particular situation the colour of the grid is defined by user actions so must be done via c#.